# Batch Insert with generated keys deals duplicate entry on unique

Tags: mysql, batch-file, insert, key, generated

I am using MySql with JDBC...the below is my table definition

```
CREATE TABLE `A` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unq` (`type`(50),`value`(50))
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

At the moment i am using statement in order to batch insert rows to that table with `RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` option in order to relate the id to other table.

I want the ability to perform that operation but when / if DUPLICATE ENTRY occur ( the same combination of type & value ) to continue with the transaction as like nothing happens but still to get the generated keys, and if DUPLICATE ENTRY occur retrieve the existing key.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `IGNORE` keyword

```
INSET IGNORE ....
```

as Quoted in [`Mysql`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)

> If you use the IGNORE keyword, errors that occur while executing the
>   INSERT statement are treated as warnings instead. For example, without
>   IGNORE, a row that duplicates an existing UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY
>   value in the table causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is
>   aborted. With IGNORE, the row still is not inserted, but no error is
>   issued.

alternative syntax

[INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: But will it still retrieves the id of the existing entry?